# What's the correct way to construct a custom date/time string format that can be localized in .NET?

Tags: .net, localization

I need a date string with one digit for the month, one digit for the day and two digits for the year (which is `M/d/yy` in the US, `d/M/yy` in most other places). I also need it to work across locales so it should automatically deal with the order of month/day and the separator. The closest to this is the `d` format which returns `MM/dd/yyyy` when called via `date.ToString("d")`.

This needs to work across locales, so I tried this is what I came up with:

```
string format = culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
                                   .Replace("yyyy", "yy")
                                   .Replace("dd", "d")
                                   .Replace("MM", "M");

return date.ToString(format);
```

Using `culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` gives me the date format used for the `d` date format. Using this property will take care of the ordering of day/month/year and the date separator.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want it to work with culture then you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definitely want *exactly* the format `M/d/yy` then just use that:

```
return date.ToString("M/d/yy", culture);
```

However, that isn't necessarily an *appropriate* string for the culture. For example, it would be rather alien to anyone in the UK, which would expect more of a `d/M/yy` format - day before month.

Note that the `MM/dd/yyyy` format may be what you get when you use `date.ToString("d")` but that's definitely not what you'd get in the UK.

Basically, you need to decide whether you want to nail down the format, in which case you're blowing localization - or whether you want to use the "normal" culture-specific short date string format, in which case `date.ToString("d", culture)` would make sense.

It sounds like you may be trying to go half way - "the short date format, but definitely don't use 4-digit years" etc. While that *could* work (make sure you pass `culture` into the `ToString` method as well) there's no guarantee that the culture's short date pattern will be using `dd` etc to start with. It could go horribly wrong, for example if the normal short date format is `ddd dd MMM yyyy` you'd end up with `dd d MM yy`, so something like "09 9 06 12" for June 9th 2012.

Basically, unless you've *actually* got a mapping from culture to "even shorter date format" I wouldn't suggest fudging it like this.

EDIT: Here's a short program whose output you should check. Basically it prints the original format and the modified one.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var culture in 
                        CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
        {
            string original = culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            string modified = original.Replace("yyyy", "yy")
                                      .Replace("dd", "d")
                                      .Replace("MM", "M");
            Console.WriteLine("{0,11}: {1,12} => {2,-9}",
                              culture, original, modified);
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine, scanning down the list quickly, I think you'd actually be okay. Nothing seems to use `ddd` or `MMM` in the original format. But there's no guarantee that that will continue to be the case...

Comment: Updated question to reflect that I do need it to work with culture info. From what I've seen on MSDN, `culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` gives me the format used for `d` which is the closest thing I have to what I need, which is why I'm tweaking it.

Comment: @Omar: Yes, the whole point of `d` is to give you the `ShortDatePattern`. I'm just saying that you're basing "what you want to see" on what the US short date pattern is. Have you looked at what happens when you apply your change to the short date patterns for all cultures? (Will add this to my answer...)

Comment: So the "correct" way to do what I want would be have a mapping of the date format in each culture. This also applies for all other custom date formats, there's no way around not having to deal with the culture.

Comment: @Omar: Yup, unfortunately so. Of course, if your app doesn't need to handle many cultures, that shouldn't be so hard. You could always have a mapping table for ones you know about, and fall back to the short date format for others.